# addEventListener not working in Javascript but jQuery Click is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using modular pattern of javascript and trying to do things in Javascript way rather than Jquery

```
myapp.module1 = (function($){
"use strict";

var _config = {
    backgroundImages : document.getElementsByClassName('img_paste'),
}

for(var i = 0;i < _config.backgroundImages.length; i++){
var imageElement = _config.backgroundImages[i];
imageElement.addEventListener('click',myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage(imageElement),false);
}

// $('.img_paste').click(function(){
//  var img = this;
//  console.log(this);
//  console.log($(this));

//  myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage(img);
// });


})(jQuery);
```

In the above code, the Jquery click function works but not the Javacript one.

When I tried to debug, I tried to **console out** the image in `addBackgroundImage()` function.

```
var addBackgroundImage = function(imageToBeAdded){
    console.log(imageToBeAdded);// 
    _addImageToCanvas(imageToBeAdded);
}
```

The function seems to be executing even before `onclick`. Why is that happening?

First, the images elements appear to be empty in the console, then after some some the image elements are displayed in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this simple code example:

```
function describeTheParameter(p) {
    console.log("describeTheParameter invoked. p is of type " + typeof(p));
}

function stringFunction() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

describeTheParameter(stringFunction());
describeTheParameter(stringFunction);
```

This results in

> describeTheParameter invoked. p is of type string
>
> describeTheParameter invoked. p is of type function

In the first call, we are calling `stringFunction`, and then passing *the result* to `describeTheParameter`.

In the second call, we are actually passing the *function* to `describeTheParameter`.

When you call `addEventListener` you must follow the pattern of the second call: pass the function without invoking it:

---

In the following line of code, you are invoking `addBackgroundImage`, and then passing the result (which will be `undefined`) to `addEventListener`.

```
imageElement.addEventListener('click',myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage(imageElement),false);
```

You need to pass a yet-to-be-called function into `addEventListener`.

The smallest step to make your code work is to employ a currying function:

```
function addImage(imageElement) {
      return function() {
          myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage(imageElement);
      }
}


for(var i = 0;i < _config.backgroundImages.length; i++){
    var imageElement = _config.backgroundImages[i];
    imageElement.addEventListener('click', addImage(imageElement), false);
}
```

For much simpler code, make use of the `this` keyword. In this case, `this` will point to the element that's firing the event.

```
function imageClickHandler() {
    var imageElement = this;
    myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage(imageElement);
}

for(var i = 0;i < _config.backgroundImages.length; i++){
   var imageElement = _config.backgroundImages[i];
   imageElement.addEventListener('click', imageClickHandler, false);
}
```

Comment: This worked..thank you so much, but I am still not able to comprehend your solution, I load all my images first and at the bottom have placed the scripts, why doesnt it work for what I tried?

Comment: Hi Andrew..I am in a learning stage so pls bear with me, I tried out both of your solutions, why is it necessary to return the function in your first solution cos in your second solution you are just executing the function... I tried to execute function instead of returning it in your first solution, but it wont work! Whats the difference?

Comment: @Abhinav In that first one `addImage` is not what is being assigned as the click handler, it is actually executing immediately and returning an anonymous function, which is what is actually assigned as the click handler. That new function will have access to the value of the `imageElement` that was passed into `addImage` via [closure](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/).

Comment: @Abhinav - I've written an open paragraph. I think this should explain the underlying concept.

Answer (score 2):

> The function seems to be executing even before onclick. Why is that happening?

Look at the statement you wrote:

> ```
> myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage(imageElement)
> ```

You are **calling** the function and then passing its return value as the function argument.

You want something more along the lines of:

```
myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage.bind(myapp.module2, imageElement)
```

(or the function expression that you used in the commented out code)

Comment: Where should I specify the click event here? cudn get you

Comment: @Abhinav — In the same place. You just change the bit of code I was talking about.

Comment: `imageElement.addEventListener('click', myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage.bind(myapp.module2, imageElement), false);`. What this is doing is similar to what is happening in the first solution @Andrew Shepherd purposed. This is using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function that when called, calls `myapp.module2.addBackgroundImage` with the value of `imageElement` (at the time `bind` was called) as its argument.